# Terminal delay when running c code in windows

Tags: c, terminal

My terminal is getting delayed while running c code lately. When I try to type something, the terminal doesn't change and a few seconds later what I typed comes out right away. I'm using windows 11 and I installed c with MinGW.

```
gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I've tried running through Vs code and Dev-c++, but both are having a delay of around 7 second even though it only prints Hello World. I have also tried changing the terminal I am using, and the result is still delayed. However, when I run the python code, the terminal runs smoothly without any delay.

This is the code that I run.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result.

```
Hello World
--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.322 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here and it was my fault. is my question better?